# Find out |a+p+b+q| for the following question.

Tags: calculus

Let$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    ax(x-1)+b&;x\lt1\\
    x+2&;1\le x\le3\\
    px^2+qx+2&;x\gt3
\end{cases}$$ is continuous for all x belongs to R except $x=1$ but $|f(x)|$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x)$ is continuous at x=3 and $|a+p+b+q|=k$, then k=?

Comment: I think you just have to include your attempts to avoid your question from getting closed. you should be able to derive some equations with the conditions given to you.

Comment: are you sure the second condition is $1\leq x \leq 3 $?

Answer (score 1):

> $f′(x)$ is continuous at $x=3$

So derivatives of $x+2$ and $px^2 + qx + 2$ must be equal.

$1=2px + q$; $x=3$

$\boxed{1=6p + q}$

> continuous for all x belongs to R except x=1
>   but |f(x)|
>    is differentiable everywhere

So it's graph should be like this (drawed very roughly, slopes should be equal at $x=1$)

[image]

If $x+2$ is positive at $x=1$, then $ax(x−1)+b$ must be negative.

If $x+2$ is negative at $x=1$, then $ax(x−1)+b$ must be positive.

So $ax(x−1)+b = -x-2$ for $x=1$

$a(0) + b = -3$

$\boxed{b=-3}$

Also the derivatives of $ax(x−1)+b$ and $-x-2$ must be equal too. (at $x=1$)

$2ax-a= -1$

$\boxed{a= -1}$

Jump to

> $f′(x)$ is continuous at $x=3$

$x+2$ and $px^2 + qx + 2$ must be equal for $x=3$

$9p + 3q + 2 = 5$
$\boxed{3p + q = 1}$

Remember, we found that $1=6p + q$

Solving system of equations $1=6p + q$ and $3p + q = 1$

$\boxed{p=0,q=1}$

Now, $|0+1-1-3| = 3$, the answer should be $3$.

And our function is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    -x(x-1)-3&;x\lt1\\
    x+2&;1\le x\le3\\
    x+2&;x\gt3
\end{cases}$$